# Shorten Code Logic For String Manipulation

Tags: regex

Examples
`"123456"` would be `["123", "456"]`.

`"1234567891011"` would be `["123", "456", "789", "10", "11"]`.

I have come up with this logic using regex to solve the challenge but I am being asked if there is a way to make the logic shorter.

```
def ft(str)

end
```

The result from the scan gives a lot of whitespaces so after the join operation, I am left with either a double dash or triple dashes so I used this `.gsub(/-+/, '-')` to fix that. I also noticed sometimes there is a dash at the begin or the end of the string, so I used `.gsub(/^-|-$/, '')` to fix that too

Any Ideas?

Comment: Tip: `return` is implicit in Ruby, so it can be omitted here.

Comment: @engineersmnky So How do I add the - in between the groups?

Comment: Using [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

Comment: @engineersmnky the .then throws a undefined method `then' for

Comment: Your question should include a usable string that includes non-digit characters so we have a fully functioning reproducible example to copy/paste.

Comment: Its unclear whether you need dashes in your output or not.  Please edit the question to clearly provide the desired output.  You mention dashes but show no dashes in your examples.

Comment: My edit may have messed up your question (in which case please accept my apologies), but you didn't change it in your subsequent edit so I'm not sure what you are asking. Moreover, your example strings contain only digits so I don't understand the purpose of  `.gsub(/-+/, '-')`. You need to clarify your question. More generally, when you give an example show the expected result (which must be a valid Ruby object). Also, you originally said, "5551231234 would be grouped like this 555 123 12 34", but neither 5551231234 nor 555 123 12 34 is a valid Ruby object. The first (e.g.) must be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

- Slice the string in chunks of max 3 digits. (`s.scan(/.{1,3}/`)
- Check if the last chunk has only 1 character. If so, take the last char of the chunk before and prepend it to the last.
- Glue the chunks together using `join(" ")`

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [@steenslag's recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74942302/1978251). (There are quite a few other ways to achieve the same with varying levels of verbosity and esotericism)

Here is how I would go about it:

```
def format_str(str)
  numbers = str.delete("^0-9").scan(/.{1,3}/)
  # there are a number of ways this operation can be performed
  numbers.concat(numbers.pop(2).join.scan(/../)) if numbers.last.length == 1 
  numbers.join('-')
end
```

Breakdown:

- `numbers = str.delete("^0-9")` - delete any non numeric character from the string
- `.scan(/.{1,3}/)` - scan them into groups of 1 to 3 characters
- `numbers.concat(numbers.pop(2).join.scan(/../)) if numbers.last.length == 1` - If the last element has a length of 1 then remove the last 2 elements join them and then scan them into groups of 2 and add these groups back to the Array
- `numbers.join('-')` - join the numbers with a hyphen to return a formatted String

Example:

```
require 'securerandom'
10.times do 
  s = SecureRandom.hex 
  puts "Original: #{s} => Formatted: #{format_str(s)}"
end 
# Original: fd1bbce41b1c784ce6ad5303d868bbe9 => Formatted: 141-178-465-303-86-89
# Original: af04bd4d4d6beb5a0412a692d5d3d42d => Formatted: 044-465-041-269-253-42
# Original: 9a1833a43cbef51c3f3c21baa66fe996 => Formatted: 918-334-351-332-166-996
# Original: 4104ae13c998cec896997b9919bdafb3 => Formatted: 410-413-998-896-997-991-93
# Original: 0eb49065472240ba32b3c029f897b30d => Formatted: 049-065-472-240-323-029-897-30
# Original: 4c68f9f68e8f6132c0ed5b966d639cf4 => Formatted: 468-968-861-320-596-663-94
# Original: 65987ee04aea8fb533dbe38c0fea7d63 => Formatted: 659-870-485-333-807-63
# Original: aa8aaf1cf59b52c9ad7db6d4b1ae0cbb => Formatted: 815-952-976-410
# Original: 8eb6b457059f91fd06ccbac272db8f4e => Formatted: 864-570-599-106-272-84
# Original: 1c65825ed59dcdc6ec18af969938ea57 => Formatted: 165-825-596-189-699-38-57
```

That being said to modify your existing code this will work as well:

```
def format_str(str)
 str
    .delete("^0-9")
    .scan(/(?=\d{5})\d{3}|(?=\d{3}$)\d{3}|\d{2}/)
    .join('-') 
end
```

Comment: The improved regex in the second example is a key change that addresses almost all issues in the original question.  Nice work @engineersmnky

Answer (score 1):

Here are three more ways to do that.

---

**Use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regular expression**

```
def fmt(str)
  str.delete("^0-9").scan(/\d{2,3}(?!\d\z)/)
end
```

The regular expression reads, "match two or three digits provided they are not followed by a single digit at the end of the string". `(?!\d\z)` is a *negative lookahead* (which is not part of the match). As matches are *greedy* by default, the regex engine will always match three digits if possible.

**Solve by recursion**

```
def fmt(str)
  recurse(str.delete("^0-9"))
end
```

```
def recurse(s) 
  case s.size
  when 2,3
    [s]
  when 4
    [s[0,2], s[2,2]]
  else
    [s[0,3], *fmt(s[3..])]
  end
end
```

**Determine the last two matches from the size of the string**

```
def fmt(str)
  s = str.delete("^0-9")
  if s.size % 3 == 1
    s[0..-5].scan(/\d{3}/) << s[-4,2] << s[-2,2] 
  else
    s.scan(/\d{2,3}/)
  end
end
```

---

All methods exhibit the following behaviour.

```
["5551231234", "18883319", "123456", "1234567891011"].each do |str|
   puts "#{str}: #{fmt(str)}"
end
5551231234: ["555", "123", "12", "34"]
18883319: ["188", "833", "19"]
123456: ["123", "456"]
1234567891011: ["123", "456", "789", "10", "11"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Without changing your code too much and without adjusting your actual regex, I might suggest replacing `scan` with `split` in order to avoid all the extra nil values; replacing `gsub` with `tr` which is much faster; and then using `reject(&:empty?)` to loop through and remove any blank array elements before joining with whatever character you want:

```
string = "12345fg\n\t\t\t          67"

string.tr("^0-9", "")
.split(/(?=\d{5})(\d{3})|(?=\d{3}$)(\d{3})|(\d{1,2})/)
.reject(&:empty?)
.join("-")
#=>  123-45-67
```

Answer (score 0):

*An* approach:

```
def foo(s)
  s.gsub(/\D/, '').scan(/\d{1,3}/).each_with_object([]) do |x, arr| 
    if x.size == 3 || arr == [] 
      arr << x 
    else 
      y = arr.last
      arr[-1] = y[0...-1]
      arr << "#{y[-1]}#{x}" 
    end 
  end
end
```

Remove all non-digits characters, then scan for 1 to 3 digit chunks. Iterate over them. If it's the first time through or the chunk is three digits, add it to the array. If it isn't, take the last digit from the previous chunk and prepend it to the current chunk and add that to the array.

Alternatively, without generating a new array.

```
def foo(s)
  s.gsub(/\D/, '').scan(/\d{1,3}/).instance_eval do |y|
    y.each_with_index do |x, i|
      if x.size == 1 
        y[i] = "#{y[i-1][-1]}#{x}"
        y[i-1] = y[i-1][0...-1]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Not suggesting this is the best approach, but wanted to offer a little food for thought:

You can basically reduce the logic for your challenge to test for 1 single condition and to use 2 very simple pattern matches:

**Condition to test for**: Number of characters is more than 3 and has a modulo(3) of 1.  This condition will require the use of both pattern matches.

All other conditions will use a single pattern match so no reason to test for those.

This could probably be made a little less verbose but it’s all spelled out pretty well for clarity:

```
def format(s)
  n = s.delete("^0-9")
  regex_1 = /.{1,3}/
  regex_2 = /../
  
  if [n.length-3, 0].max.modulo(3) == 1
    a = n[0..-5].scan(regex_1)+n[-4..-1].scan(regex_2)
  else a=n.scan(regex_1)
  end
  a.join("-")
end
```

Comment: I am not sure the `-3` is needed in `s.length-3` you could just add `return s if  s.delete!("^0-9").length < 3` as a guard clause (first line of method body). Additionally might want to mention this method will mutate `s`

Comment: @engineersmnky, I modified the answer so that it doesn’t mutate the original string.  I wasn’t actually focused on the specifics like that and just wanted to get my basic logic path across without any extra method calls to interrupt general readability, but since you brought it up, I went ahead and changed it.  As to the reference to '''-3''', I’m not sure your alternative has the same effect.  I was also trying to use a single method chain to make it more clear that I was only testing for the one condition.  It’s just how my brain works.  IOW, I did t think it would help highlight the logic.